# Sending Email in php, headers problems

Tags: php

I trying to send email using mail() function...
here is my code:

```
     <html>
     <form action ="" method ="post">
     <input type="submit" name= "email" value="email">
     <form>

     <?php

     if (isset($_POST['email']))
     {

     mail("receiver@hotmail.com", "Subject: Hi", "hello" );

     echo "Mail Sent";
     }
     ?> 
     </html>
```

the code about works just fine, I can get the email but the only problem was when I check the email, the sender will be "**webmaster@something.org**"

I tried to change the code to:

```
     mail("receiver@hotmail.com", "Subject: Hi","hello", "From: sender@yahoo.com"  );
```

but it didn't work...
Could you please help me to include the name of the person who sent the email...
Thank a lot

Answer (score 2):

Please try this.It is the simplest method to mail someone.

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check php [mail manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).
You need to define 'From: xxx' in the header

Answer (score 0):

check your form tag closed or not?

```
<?php
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [phpmailer to send the mail.

You can set the sender id and content type for the mail.